# Не сохраняются данные в БД sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Всем привет, недавно начал изучать python+flask+html, в основном пишу на verilog так что могу не понимать очевидных вещей.
Пытаюсь сделать небольшой сайт для себя и коллег "трекер железок". Возникла следующая проблема: когда отправляю форму через post, то данные "не сохраняются".
Вот код на python (наверное не лучший, что вы видели):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class SaveClass(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    use = db.Column(db.Integer)
    leave = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<SaveClass %r' % self.id


@app.route('/', method=['POST', 'GET'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # -----------------------  90  -------------------------------#
        table_90 = SaveClass.query.get(0)
        if request.form.get('use_90'):
            table_90.use = 1
        else:
            table_90.use = 0

        if request.form.get('leave_90'):
            table_90.leave = 1
        else:
            table_90.leave = 0

        table_90.name = request.form.get('name_90')

        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return "error"

    else:
        table_data = SaveClass.query.all()
        return render_template("index.html", table_data=table_data)
```

Использую flask и sqlite.
С помощью `if request.form.get('leave_90')` я проверяю была ли поставлена галочка в checkbox.
Картина следующая: я ставлю галочку в чекбокс, отправляю, страница обновляется, галочка просто пропадает (хотя по задумке должна остаться до тех пор пока ее не снимут ручками). Надеюсь я объяснил понятно.

Comment: Странный код внутри класса с `if request.method == 'POST':`, точно в коде нет проблем с отступами?

Comment: Здесь нет проблем с отступами, здесь потеряли напрочь кусок кода. В модели вообще и в помине этого кода, начинающегося с `if request.method == 'POST':`, быть не должно. Он должен быть в обработчике, функции с декоратором `@app.route(<URL>)`, это же он запрос принимает, а не модель и уж тем более не функция `__repr__`, она должна быть в одну строчку.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/346306/ есть очень полная и весьма доходчивая обучалка по фласк, советую с ней максимально детально ознакомиться и многие вопросы отпадут сами собой.

Comment: @mrEvgenX вы правы потерял кусок кода, когда формировал вопрос, исправил.
За ссылку спасибо, обязательно посмотрю.

Comment: Я выяснил, что изменения не происходят, из-за того что не выполняется условие ` if request.form.get('use_90'): ` , но я не понимаю почему.
Вот так этот checkbox добавлен в html `<td><input title="Использую" type="checkbox" id="use_90" name="use_90"  {% if table_data[0].use==1 %}checked{% else %}{% endif %}></td>`

Comment: Вопрос решил. Ошибка была в html части. Решилось оборачиванием всего, что есть в теге <main> в один тег <form>. Всем спасибо, кто пытался помочь.